# Best Way to Close a Win Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to close a form on a button click event.Here in my example I am hiding the form.Think this is not a good way.When I do only Close() the form is disposed forever and need to rerun the programme to retrieve  it.

```
private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close(); //closing frmCalender 
}

private void frmCalender_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
        this.Hide();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Give me the best way to close a C# Windows Form.

Comment: Why do you think the way you're doing it right now is not good enough? It is very common approach if you need to hide form instead of closing.

Comment: Hard to guess what this is about.  Not much point in writing this.Close() when you know it is actually going to Hide() anyway.  There's just more than one way to close a window, the user can also click the Close button or press Alt+F4.  What is supposed to happen then?

Comment: I only use .Hide when I want the calling .ShowDialog to continue execution. Otherwise I call .Close as the form instance is no longer needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to close a form, call `.Close()`.

> When I do only Close() the form is disposed forever and need to rerun the programme to retrieve it.

When you close the form, I assume you have no references to it. If so, you can create a new copy of your form via the constructor (`var form = new MyForm();`).

Otherwise, after closing the form, I believe you should be able to call `.Show()` on it again, as long as something still has a reference to your form.

Comment: This is a good answer, except the last paragraph, which is wrong. For a non-modal dialog, the `Close` method also calls `Dispose`.

Answer (score -1):

I think, the best approach would be:

```
private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide(); 
}
```

Comment: Not quite. It will hide form on specific button click (`buttonClose` in this case) , but still close on click by "standard" clos button in the window caption.

Comment: if so, the code should stay as it is.  There is no need to change anything in the original code.  However, if the form's close button is hidden, my code would be the best :)

Comment: You may call me pedant, but again: not quite ;) even if close button is hidden, user can close window by Alt-F4 keyboard shortcut.

Comment: This is merely an inferior attempt at producing the same effect as the code shown in the question.

Comment: I forgot about Alt+F4 :).  Generally, I would not use this approach. If a form is closed, it is better to let it die and create a new one when needed.  If a form is not closed, just bring it to front.